# Get key from button list when pressed in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I am displaying a list of [Material Kit buttons](https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit) (using [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist)) and want to be able to display their key (ie. their index) when they are clicked - however am struggling with the getting it working with an MK button.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks a ton!

**Button builder with onPress:**

```
AllConnectionsItemButton = MKButton.flatButton()
  .withOnPress( (key) => alert(key))
  .build()
```

**SectionList:**

```
<SectionList
  renderItem={({item, index, section}) => (
  <AllConnectionsItemButton key={index}>
    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
  </AllConnectionsItemButton>
    )}
  renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
    <View>
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  )}
  sections={this.state.myList}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
/>
```